# Number of ways to decompose a full binary tree

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a full binary tree $T$, we decompose it into multiple sub-trees which are also required to be full binary trees. Our question is: how many different ways of decomposition are there? This figure illustrates two ways of decomposition.[image]

Comment: Assuming labelled trees, I get the absolute value of [A264610](https://oeis.org/A264610).

Comment: @YCor Thank you, but your answer may not be correct, as you may have different ways of decomposition for the left and right sub-trees

Comment: @PeterTaylor I am more interested in unlabelled trees.

Comment: If $n$ is the number of levels (so the $n$th complete tree has $2^n - 1$ vertices) then from $n=0$ I get $1, 1, 2, 4, 11, 44, 269, 2651, 42096, \ldots$, which is not in OEIS.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Could you pls explain how you arrive at the numbers?

Comment: [Direct calculation](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdj8FOhDAQhu8kvMMELx0FIp7MJj6BF9crYU13mQVCd2hoIavGd3cK0aBN08z0_-fLPzM8wctg3nm4dNq8dtyo_T6F5CNJ4RHzhtgpjCM_Er25VltyMlAWVRzZsWOvEhZjMrHRRzKG6tD91vjjuk-hkCv9eRiBoWMYNTek5NcQqxnvCtzFEci5gWciC74l6H0LfrBimck4mfL65EFzHVReLA-HHhRnPWaLCUJQB3okcddkSR72K3izQ65tkJSbLmou-6yo4Harl0KsDkrgCCFx_ycxS1jEFbrux-saW4Iw87o7eYWYwn_BTUenPuG6g2LhXwN_hi_Eb4BVfNE=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Could you pls explain the key step in the code?

Comment: As per the comment: pick the size of the complete binary tree which contains the root, slice off below that, recurse on the sliced off trees.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Could you pls be more explicite? I still cannot get the recursive form. Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know how to be more explicit than the code, so on the assumption that the sticking point is Sage syntax: we build a g.f. using variables $z_i$ to represent complete binary trees on $2^i-1$ vertices. E.g. the two examples in the image are represented by $z_2^5 + z_1 z_3^2$. Let $t_n$ be the g.f. for possible decompositions of the complete binary tree on $2^n-1$ vertices. $t_0 = 1$ and for $n > 0$, $$t_n = \sum_{k=1}^n z_k t_{n-k}^{2^k}$$ Evaluate $t_n(1,1,1,\ldots)$ to count labelled trees or count the distinct terms in $t_n$ for unlabelled trees.